# Setting a bit field in C

Tags: c, field, bit, bit-fields

I'm trying to write a function that will set a field of bits to a certain value. The function is `int setField(int old, int hi, int lo, int new)`. I need it to take the range of bits (`lo` to `hi`) from the old value and replace them with the new value. The function must return the new value (in decimal) after the range of bits has been replaced.

```
int setField (int oldValue, int hi, int lo, int newValue) 
{
    int old = (oldValue >> lo) & ( (1 << hi) - 1);

    int i;
    for(i = lo;i<=hi;i++)
    {
    int a = getBit(newValue,i);
    if(a == 1)
      setBit(newValue,i);
    if(a == 0)
      clearBit(newValue,i);
    }
    return newValue;
}
```

Here is the code for clearbit and setbit

```
int setBit (int value, int position)
{
     int a = (1<<position);

     return (value | a);
}

int clearBit (int value, int position)
{
    int a = (1 << position);

    return (value & (~(a)) );
}
```

I'm having trouble returning the new value (after the bits are modified) any help would be appreciated.

Also here is the code for getBit

```
int getBit (int value, int position)
{
    int a = (1<<position);
    if( (value & a) == 0)
      return 0;
    else if( (value & a) != 0)
      return 1;
}
```

Comment: `setBit` and `clearBit` return the new value, but you're not doing anything with the result when you call it.

Comment: You're also getting the old bit from the wrong argument.

Comment: Your '(in decimal)' comment is curious — I think you should remove it.  The value will be in binary.

Comment: You could simplify `getBit()` to: `int getBit(int value, int position) { return (value & (1 << position)) != 0; }`.  Or you can keep `a` as an intermediate variable.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to do this without a loop:

```
uint32_t setField(uint32_t old, int hi, int lo, uint32_t new)
{
    uint32_t mask = -(2 << hi) ^ -(1 << lo);
    return (old & ~mask) | (new & mask);
}
```

The construct being used for `mask` here generates a mask of the form e.g. `0b000..00011111000` for hi=7, lo=4.

Negation is used to create the masks here because negating a single-bit-set integer (like `1 << lo`) results in a value with the same bit set, as well as all higher bits. For example:

```
  1 << 4  =  16 = 0b000…0010000
-(1 << 4) = -16 = 0b111…1110000
```

XORing two such masks together results in a value with a range of bits set where the two masks differ.

Note that this assumes that you want to replace the range of bits with the corresponding range from `new`. If you actually want to start with the lowest bit in `new`, replace `new` in the last line with `(new << lo)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the result and use it to assign the variable before you return it:

```
newValue = clearBit(newValue,i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `oldValue` in the calls to `setBit` or `clearBit`, and assign the result back to `oldValue`.

```
int setField (int oldValue, int hi, int lo, int newValue) 
{
    int i;
    for(i = lo;i<=hi;i++)
    {
      int a = getBit(newValue,i);
      if(a == 1) {
        oldValue = setBit(oldValue,i);
      } else {
        oldValue = clearBit(oldValue,i);
      }
    }
    return oldValue;
}
```

There's also no need to test explicitly for `a == 0`, just use an `else` clause.

Comment: You might have misunderstood me , let's say i give an old value of 6 which is 0000 0110 , and i set hi to be 3 (the 3rd bit) and lo to be 0 (the first bit) so now the range is 0110 . Now i pass 5 as new value which is 0101 . What the function needs to do is change that 0110 to 0101 and then return the value of 0000 0101 in decimal (5 in this case).

Comment: OK, it seems like I just have old and new reversed. You were using `newValue` for everything in your code.

Comment: I tried what you wrote and i just got old value returned unchanged .

Comment: I forgot to fix the `return` statement

Comment: BTW, numbers aren't in decimal or binary, they're just numbers. They don't become decimal or binary until you print them in a particular base.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Add it as an update to your question.

Comment: That looks like my incorrect answer. I fixed the answer like you said.